# How to test setting a field to empty string using webdriverio, mocha and phantomjs?

Tags: jquery, testing, phantomjs, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I am testing the appearance of a tooltip when users do not enter anything in a field using webdriverio, mocha and phantomjs. Below is the test code:

```
// failing test
describe ('Test appearance of a tooltip upon entering nothing', function(){
  before(function(){
    return browser.url(site);
  });

  before(function(){
    return browser.setValue('#id_field1', '', 'tab')// mimicking users entering nothing
  });

  it('should notify users via a tooltip "Enter a valid lotno"', function(){
    return browser.getHTML('body')
      .then(function(form, done){
        return form.should.contain('Enter a valid lotno');
          setTimeout(done, 1000);
      });
    }); // it block ends here
  });// describe block ends for tooltip tests
```

This does not show the tooltip text.

I have another test where if users enter an incorrect value, it should show a tooltip text and this works just as expected. Below is the passing test:

```
// passing test
describe ('Test appearance of a tooltip upon entering non numbers', function(){

  before(function(){
    return browser.url(site);
  });

  before(function(){
    return browser.setValue('#id_field1', 'JKJK', 'tab')// mimicking users entering non numbers
  });

  it('should notify users via a tooltip "Numbers only please"', function(){
    return browser.getHTML('body')
      .then(function(form, done){
        return form.should.contain('Numbers only please');
          setTimeout(done, 1000);
      });
  }); // it block ends here
});// describe block ends for tooltip tests
```

How can I test users entering nothing and make the tooltip appear? When I tested these steps directly in the site, both tooltips appear as expected.

Comment: A user can hardly enter *nothing* into a field. You probably need to mimic the user behavior of clicking into the field and then clicking somewhere else.

Comment: I was hoping that pressing tab would mimic that behavior!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try the following :

```
before(function(){
    return browser.setValue('#id_field1', ['', 'Tab']);
});
```

Apparently the usage of setValue supports sending an array of values : https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/84. Alternatively you could use the keys command. http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/keys.html

Comment: I tried sending an array `browser.setValue('#id_field1', ['', 'tab'])` and it shows a tooltip text that corresponds to entering non numbers!  I am not sure how to use the `client.keys(...)` as the documentation is not that clear.

Comment: Sounds like you've got some debugging to do. Pay attention to what your tests are actually doing. Were any characters entered into the fields? If no characters were entered then it sounds like there's a bug with the tooltip. Also, did you try sending Tab instead of tab?

Comment: thanks so much for pointing out the 'Tab'. I was using 'tab' instead, my bad, now it working :)

Comment: Yes, I accepted it, thanks, got pulled away into a meeting!

Comment: If you want to trigger the onChange you should first do a click on the element and then use .keys(). http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/keys.html